# Access 2007 SQL - Get Values From Table that Match Values in an Array?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to populate a multi-column combobox as follows.
I have an array with the Employee ID numbers of several employees.
E.g., Eid$(1)="001", Eid$(2)="005", Eid$(3)="214"

Now, I want to use SQL something like this:

Me.Combo1.RowSource="SELECT empid, lastname, firstname, age FROM Employees ORDER BY lastname ASC 
WHERE empid = a value in array Eid$()"

I realize this isn't correct syntax, but I hope it explains what I'm trying to do.

After execution, the combobox will have values like this:

005 Able Charles 52

214 Baker James 31

001 Smith, Nancy 46

Each day the array will have a different set of Employee IDs.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Dump your array to the table and join this table with Employees by empid

Comment: That sounds good.  It would be great if you could show me the code for doing the two steps - dumping to a table; and joining.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Populating the combobox in your form_load event would be one way.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim arrayValue As Integer
arrayValue = Eid$()

Me.Combo1.RowSource="SELECT empid, lastname, firstname, age FROM Employees WHERE empid = " & arrayValue & " ORDER BY lastname ASC;"

End Sub
```

I am not quite sure if a rowsource can be a query String. I know that creating a recordset first and setting the recordset as the rowsource works for sure.